# Executing local script/command on remote server

Tags: linux, unix, remote, gnu

I have a command that I want to run on machine B from machine A. If I run the command on machine B locally, it works fine.

Here is the command:

```
for n in `find /data1/ -name 'ini*.ext'` ; do  echo cp $n "`dirname $n `/` basename $n 
.ext`"; done
```

From machine A, I issue this command

```
ssh user@machineB  for n in `find /data1/ -name 'ini*jsem'` ; do  echo cp $n "`dirname $n `/` basename $n .jsem`"; done
```

But I get error `syntax error near unexpected token do`

What is wrong? I think it has something to do with double quotes, single quotes, semi colon because executing command  `ssh user@machineB ls` works fine. So not issue of authentication or something else.

Thanks

Comment: Answer is to use a script and then issue 

ssh user@machineB 'bash -s ' < script

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your local shell is interpreting part of the command. You need to quote the entire command so that the remote shell executes it.

```
ssh user@machineB 'for n in `find /data1/ -name "ini*jsem"` ; do  echo cp $n "`dirname $n `/` basename $n .jsem`"; done'
```